# CSS: Responsive google maps on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a google maps Section on my website for my contact page. In my browser the css for the map is

```
<div class="googlemap" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px;">
<iframe style="border: 0;" src="map" width="50%" height="600" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen">
</iframe>
</div>
```

In a **smarthphone view** i get the half map and aligned in left as shown below.

[Google maps on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9mxn.png)

I want to apply CSS that makes my map responsive on mobile.
I try something like the following but it doesnt work

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.googlemap{

  //these are the ideal margins for my mobile view
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: -350px;
}
```

How to set this properly working?

Comment: Try setting width="auto"

Comment: nothing happends:(

Comment: Try removing all inline styles and placing it with this .responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

Comment: if you mean ```.googlemaps{width: 100%; height: auto;}```. will not change. this is not the problem

Comment: it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Note two things that you must account for in restyling your map component:

1. Inline Styles
2. Iframe Attributes

The only way to override inline-styles from a stylesheet is to use the `important!` keyword. Read up on `specificity` to understand what is going on and some ways to overcome it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

You may also have to use the `important!` keyword to override the iframe width and height attributes.

I don't know what your expected final design should be, but you could do something like the following:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .googlemap {
    margin: 10px !important;
  }
  .googlemap > iframe {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="googlemap" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px;">
  <iframe style="border: 0;background: gray;" src="map" width="50%" height="600" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: my final design goal is to the map to fill the mobile screen

Comment: That should do it minus `10px` margin all around

Comment: your answer works for me, but i have to remove the following code in order to work ```@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9){
  
  @viewport {
  min-zoom: width/(100*vw);
  max-zoom: width/(100*vw);
  user-zoom: 0;
  }```. Can i merge them with your answer somehow?

Comment: You are getting into a different question.  You should read up on media queries to understand how they would work together. And I would recommend not using the inline styles and use more general iframe attributes to make this easier. Its' best practice to avoid `important!` where you can.

Comment: definitely i should read the queries. But please answer, can i merge the code i just provided with your code? i need my website to fit in mobile devices

Comment: What did you try? Try it and see. Experiment with it. Do you understand why the code snippet I sent works and what the media queries you removed do?

Comment: im experimenting for 3 days to make this work :D. Im trying to make both media queries work

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport